# variable n is already defined in java

Tags: java

I am trying to dynamically create objects in java uses an array

```
int  number = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter number of objects"));
        int n[] = new int[number];
        for (int i = 0 ; i < number ; i++) {
          SomeClass n[i] = new SomeClass(1,5,6);

        }
```

However the line `SomeClass n[i] = new SomeClass(1,5,6);` throw the following error

`variable n is already defined`

Comment: It is unclear what you asking. `n` is defined as `int n[]` and some lines later you define it a second time as `SomeClass n[i]` what is not allowed.

Comment: you have already declared n(i.e. int n[] = new int[number];) and you are again declaring it with different datatype(i.e. SomeClass n[i]) :p

Answer (score 4):

Your code looks like it's trying to declare `n[i]` as a variable. You don't need to do that, because `n` is already declared. You just need an assignment to the array element:

```
n[i] = new SomeClass(1, 5, 6);
```

... but you'll also need to change the type of `n`:

```
SomeClass[] n = new SomeClass[number];
```

(You *could* use `SomeClass n[]` but that style of syntax is discouraged; it's clearer if you put all the type information in one place.)

Answer (score 0):

`n` is already defined as int array  and your again trying to define it as reference of `SomeClass`, hence the error. Try to change the reference of `Someclass` to something other than `n`.

Answer (score 0):

In your code `n[i]` is an `int` because `n` is an `int[]` (array of `int`). You cannot dynamically change the type of `n[i]`.